# Problem displaying geoserver's layer when resource is updated with rest API

Tags: rest, netcdf, geoserver

I am having a weird issue when using geoserver api to update a netcdf resource of a coverage store layer. The resource is a netcdf containing one 3D (lon, ,lat, time) variable. However, the time dimension is only of length = 1. My code runs within a docker container and uses curl in a .sh file to run the api commands.

I must stress that the problem occurs only once in a while, maybe 10% of the time, maybe less.

When th problem occurs, the update of the store seems to have a problem and the layer cannot be displayed. When looking in the get Capabilities, one of the weird thing is that the time dimension is not right date, but is rather equal to 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, which is the reference date used in the netcdf for the time dimension. Also, no problems are detected in the logs.

I do know that the problem is not with the file, and probably not with the upload of the file. Indeed, when the problem occurs, I can successfully create a store and a layer with the same resource and the same parameters as the layer that is not working.
I have tried multiple things via the API to solve this issue:

- Reset the resource cache. It sometimes works, but not always
- Delete layer and store and recreating them every time I need to update the resource
- Delete resource, layer and store and recreating everything when resource update.

Nothing seems to get rid of the problem permanently. Has anyone experienced the same kind of behavior? It is not the first time I use geoserver’s api in a data harvester, but it is the first time I have this problem!

**EDIT**

I also tried to make the make the netcdf file as simple as I could, by removing the time dimension.
So now, the netcdf file only has 4 variables: lon, lat, the gridded variable, and a variable called crs that is of dimension 0, so is empty (I left it there for now since it comes from the outside source file).
But then again, the same kind of issue occurs, and again only once in a while. However, when it occurs, there seems to be something wrong caught in geoserver's log:

*2022-06-08 16:01:28,267 WARN [operation.projection] - Possible use of "Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator" projection outside its valid area.
Longitude 2147483287°00.0'W is out of range (±180°).*

But again, if when this happens, I can usually clear the resource cache and the layer will become visible again.

So I still dont know what is happening. Could it be the empty crs variable that sometimes creates problems?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hello, even with the curl commands in "verbose" mode, there is nothing suggesting that there is a problem with the store created. The logs of my commands are exactly the same as when the layer/store is successfully created/updated. 
Is there another place I should access the logs of geoserver? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html?highlight=logs#leveraging-geoserver-own-log

Comment: Hello, I have just edited my answer with updates of the problem and the only relevant part of the logs I could find.

Comment: it looks like the projection that GeoServer thinks your data is in is wrong

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer. That is what I think happens as well (wrong projection), but how can it only occurs once in a while? And a value of longitude of 2147483287°00.0'W seems odd considering all the longitude values of the file are between -78 and -37. Would forcing the projection solve the issue? The coordinate system is EPSG 4326.

Comment: maybe - NETCDF is weird I find

Comment: Well, converting the netcdf to geotiff and feeding the geotiff to geoserver seems to have solve the issue. So there is definitely something going on with netcdf and geoserver...! 
Thanks for your help anyway!